# two <select> always next to each other inseide <td>?

Tags: css

I have to selects inside td that's only one column in big table)and I want to make sure that they are next to each other at all times but td's width is width of these two selects. Not more.

The thing is that value to be displayed in **selects changes** based on data. So I thought I can assign fixed width to  but not sure if there is some better solution to that.

If I resize the browser window it is ok. Maybe I need to change the  properties?

```
<td>
  <select name="db2.rfthdd">
    <option value="WEI">WEI</option>
    <option value="SCOTSdatabase">SCOTSdatabase</option>
  </select>

  <select id="db2.rfttimestamp">
    <option value="20110302122831">2011-03-02-122831</option>
    <option value="20110302122442">2011-03-02-122442</option>
  </select>

</td>
```

[image: see the red boxes]

Comment: just out of my curiosity. Why was this question migrated? I find that OS visits more people but thought that webmasters is more appropriate ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could assign a width to each select to ensure that they never grow wider than your td (but then text may get cut off and be hard to read)  it's a bit of a trade of really.

Assign the width using css

```
select {width:100px;}
```

EDIT: now that i understand the question better, probably want to try setting the td not to wrap

```
<td style="white-space:nowrap;">
```

Comment: the width of selects varies so I cannot assign fixed width

Comment: so your saying you want the select's to be a static width no matter what, but you still want the entirety of the text of each select to be viewable?

Comment: I am saying that I want select's to be always next to each other & select's text has variable length & therefore I do not want to use static width for either select nor <td>

Comment: I included sample picture. I hope it helps. Note that if I resize the browser window then select's are next to each other. Can I achieve the same without resizing the window?

Comment: hey, i updatedmy answer (the whitespace should be white-space) also check the link i posted up there, it has a working example

Comment: works!!! you're legend. Thank you. Workes nicely for columns. The second one actually doesn't have any select at all.

Comment: I am glad that you could help too :-)))